# What is the difference “in the nude” vs “nude”?

Tags: phrase-usage

What is the difference between the following sentences?

1. I caught them watching tv in the nude.
2. I caught them watching tv nude.

Comment: Irrelevant side note: 'naked' means you have no clothes on. 'nekkid' means you have no clothes on and you're up to something

Comment: @Mitch And increasingly, both mean that you do actually have clothes on, just less than expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two sentences have the same meaning, but the grammar is different.

> *I caught them watching TV in the nude.*

The adjective "nude" is here a fused determiner head in the preposition phrase "in the nude" -- an idiom meaning "naked". Indirectly then, "nude" is a kind of predicative adjunct (or complement) with “them” as predicand.

> *I caught them watching TV nude.*

Again, "nude" is an adjective, though here more clearly functioning as a predicative adjunct with the object "them" as predicand.

Comment: I realise that you have exactly answered the question, but do you, personally, have a preference for one or the other ways of expressing the wording ?

Comment: I prefer the first one, possibly because of the idiomatic use of "in the nude".

Comment: Alternatively with “I” as predicand, if you’re into that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more correct to refer to the persons in the incident as 'naked', actually. 'Nude' refers to an unembarrassing situation, not one which is inappropriate.

> https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-naked-and-nude-if-any

'Nude' refers to the human form, as such.
'Naked' draws attention to the fact that it is unclothed, and - generally speaking - it would be expected to be clothed.

'Naked' derives from the Old English meaning 'bare, empty, not fully clothed'.

> http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=naked

'Nude' is the late Middle English from the Latin *nudus*, meaning 'plain or explicit'. [Quoted from my Oxford Dictionary of English]

Comment: More  correct? No, it's just a nuance of meaning.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which was *what is the difference between "nude" and "in the nude"*.

Comment: Admittedly so, but I think it is relevant and interesting, myself.